# Hadoop Installation 2.6.0 on Ubuntu 14 - Java Error

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop2

**EDIT**

I am trying to install Hadoop 2.6.0 on my Ubuntu 14 machine. I am coming across an error though.

When I am trying to set the `HOME` variable for Java it does not seem to be doing as expected.

I am on my machine as `hduser` setup specifically for running and using Hadoop. This user is a sudoer.

Some information:

```
java -version' gives the following

java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

This is the only version installed on my machine, which can be seen by running the following command:

```
update-alternatives --display java
```

Which gives the following message:

```
java - auto mode
link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1071
slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java'.
```

I then go to the following path:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
```

and the I list out the contents `ls`

```
default-java  java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

I then type `cd java*` and `pwd` which brings up the following path:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Ok, so with that information, I then copy that directory into the `.bashrc` file as follows:

```
# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

The `hadoop-env.sh` file I fill out as follows:

```
#Hadoop variables
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

I then at the terminal type `source ~/.bashrc` and then restart the terminal in order for it to set to the new Java path. When typing Hadoop -version I get the following output:

```
/usr/bin/hadoop: line 350: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/hadoop: line 434: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I do not know where to go from here.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `JAVA_HOME` to point to your `openjdk` in `hadoop-env.sh`. Add this line in `hadoop-env.sh`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

> **NOTE:** Change **JAVA_HOME** path in **.bashrc** too

**UPDATE I:**

Run these commands in terminal. (This will set java & javac in /bin to use your jdk)

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 1

sudo update-alternatives --config java

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac" 1

sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

> **NOTE:** If you dont have **java** and **javac** in the specified path, it will be inside **/jre** folder. Change it respectively.

Comment: I have both of those file paths set in the hadoop-env.sh and the .bashrc files and still no luck. When I run `hadoop version` I still get it looking for version 6 sun

Comment: Whats the result for `java -version`?

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the version, it is 1.7

Comment: looks like it was actually a problem with having it installed on my regular user side, I did a `rm -f` remove of hadoop on that side and now I can run the hadoop version command and get an answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have installed java (I mean JRE/JDK here) 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 at the same time. Which is comlpetelly ok since java installations are usually managed via alternatives subsystem.

The problem is that (contrary to your expectations) setting `JAVA_HOME` doesn't select which java is used. This is done via mentioned alternatives subsystem instead. The `JAVA_HOME` variable itself is only addtional configuration and doesn't have power to override what is being executed when one asks to start `java` process.

Moreover running `cd java*` isn't really a good idea unless you would like to go into first directory which starts with given string. Try to run `ls java*` to see my point. And again, it's ok to have multiple different versions of java here thanks to alternatives subsystem.

Another problem is that you are mixing different flavours of java which you probably don't have installed (`java-8-oracle` vs `java-6-sun` vs `java-1.6.0-openjdk`.

To check which java is installed, run:

```
alternatives --display java
```

And then based on the results, swich to one version of java and set `JAVA_HOME` accordingly.

Comment: would not `java -version` tell me what java is installed? I tried to use the `alternatives --display java` without success, I was asked if I meant `galternatives`

Comment: I also ended up using another post to un-install all versions of java and then only installing openjdk7 and when I run the command `hadoop version` it is still looking for a sun version 6, a bit perplexed now.